# How to set a new database for Entity Framework Code First project

Tags: c#, entity-framework-5

I have a Code First Entity Framework project. It utilizes my local ./SQLEXPRESS instance for the database connection.

I need to move my database to a production server. What do I need to do to point Entity Framework to a different SQL Server instance and a different database?

Comment: I set the connection string by using <connectionStrings> in my App Config and then sent the connection string name to the DbContext and that works.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By convention Code First will look for a connection string in your configuration file with the same name as your context class (the class deriving from `DbContext`).

If you wish to override this, then you can pass in the connection string name (or connection string) to the [DbContext constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg679467%28v=vs.103%29.aspx). See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/data/jj592674) for more information.